# embed radio on my website not working

Tags: flash, embed, internet-radio

Im having trouble to put a embed radio player on my website.

I just want to put the radio player that exists on this website:

http://cast3.servidorprotegido.in:2199/start/igrejaev/

On my website.

Here is the code that im trying to implement:

```
<object width="180" height="60" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
<param name="movie" value="htp://cast3.servidorprotegido.in:2199/ffmp3/ffmp3-config.swf" /> 
<param name="flashvars" value="url=http://198.245.63.57:9239/;&lang=en&codec=mp3&volume=75&tracking=false&skin=http://cast3.servidorprotegido.in:2199/ffmp3/ffmp3-mcclean.xml&title=WebRadio+-+Igreja+Evangelica+A+Graca+de+Deus+em+Cristo&jsevents=false&welcome=" /> 
 <param name="wmode" value="window" /> <param name="scale" value="noscale" /> 
 <embed src="http://cast3.servidorprotegido.in:2199/ffmp3/ffmp3-config.swf" flashvars="url=http://198.245.63.57:9239/;&lang=en&codec=mp3&volume=75&tracking=false&skin=http://cast3.servidorprotegido.in:2199/ffmp3/ffmp3-mcclean.xml&title=WebRadio+-+Igreja+Evangelica+A+Graca+de+Deus+em+Cristo&jsevents=false&welcome=" width="180" scale="noscale" height="60" wmode="window" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /> 
 </object>
```

Im trying to test it locally, on my machine, and im not having any luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is the the SWF movie & Data are At Your Server??? if not then According to Security Policy of ADOBE You will not be allowed to Fetch that data.

Here in Your case
if swff is Runinng then check the FLASHVARS,

```
url=http://198.245.63.57:9239/
```

is it Your Domain???
Checkout This Link, & read **THIRD** Point

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundLoaderContext.html

One Thing you can Do
Make two xmls & put them at both Server ( one at yours & another at Others)

```
http://www.myserver.com/crossdomain.xml
http://www.someone.com/crossdomain.xml
```

& the Conetent of crossdomain.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```